# SHELL : Sort Directory name as descending order

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have 3 folders in my server,

Assuming **folder** names are

1. workbook_20220217
2. workbook_20220407
3. workbook_20220105

Each folder consist of its respective files

I would only want to print the latest file based on date, there are 2 methods i have tried so far

The first method i tried 
Variable Declared

```
TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER=/farid/reporting/workbook

#First Method
ls $TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER *_* | sort -t_ -n -k2 | sed ':0 N;s/\n/, /;t0'
#The first method will return all its contents in the folder as well 

#The second Method i have tried

$(ls -td ${TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER}/workbook/* | head -1)
# This will return folder based on ascending order
```

Target output should be a `workbook_20220407`
What is the best approach should look into? There are no other logics i could think rather than using the date as the biggest value to determine if its the latest date

*PS i could not read folder as date modified because once folder have been transferred to my server, all 3 folders will be of the same date

****UPDATE****
I found a way to get the latest folder based on filename based on this reference : https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/174140-how-sort-files-based-file-name-having-numbers.html

```
ls | sort -t'-' -nk2.3 | tail -1
```

This will return the latest folder based on folder title , will this be safe to use ?

Also what does -nk.2.3 does and mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can list your files in a directory in reverse order with option `-r` (independent if you have selected either sort order)  See man page of `ls(1)` command for details.

The options `-n` and `-k2.3` of `sort(1)` command mean, respectively (see also `sort(1)` man page for details):

- sort numerically.  This meaning that the keys are considered as numbers and sorted accordingly.
- select fields 2 and 3 (the dot must be a comma, by the way) as **k**eys for sorting purposes.

Read the man pages of both commands, they are your friends.